# Did Google Play roll out In-App Review for Android?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

In *July 2019* there were some rumors about an IAR implementation for Android (Google Play Store). 
Now there is a IAR Test App on the store (works really bad) but seems to present the dialog (so it should be implementable).
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I'm also interested and actually has been announced today: [https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/in-app-review-api.html](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/in-app-review-api.html) [https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review)

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @gabor-vincze

> It has been announced:
> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/in-app-review-api.html
> https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-review